# Aggregate hourly data and count duplicates in pandas python

Tags: python, pandas, time-series, pivot-table

I have a dataframe df that looks like this:

| time | Hit/Miss |
| --- | --- |
| 2016-09-29 08:00:00 | FN |
| 2016-09-29 08:30:00 | FN |
| 2016-09-29 09:45:00 | TP |
| 2016-10-05 14:00:00 | FP |

`time` is imported straight from a [csv](/questions/tagged/csv) file without being set as an index, and `Hit/Miss` contains three categorical values `FN`, `TP`, and `FP`.

Now, I'd like to group the data by hour, day, and month and count how many `FN`, `TP`, `FP`'s occurred during the hour. As you can see from the brief example dataset. Now, every hour has `Hit/Miss` values.

This is what I have so far after grouping by day, which does give me the desired output:

```
df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time'])
df['year'] = df['time'].dt.year
df['month'] = df['time'].dt.month
df['day'] = df['time'].dt.day

HM_DD = pd.crosstab([df['year'],df['month'],df['day']], df['Hit/Miss'], dropna=True)
HM_MM = pd.crosstab([df['year'],df['month']], df['Hit/Miss'], dropna=True)
HM_YYMM = pd.crosstab(df['year'], df['Hit/Miss'], dropna=True)

HM_DD = HM_DD.reset_index()
```

And the output looks like the snip shot desired output here:
[image: img]

It does show what I need to see; however, I feel like there's a better way to do it. After all, I need to visualize the data by day and year (extra qn if you have time: What would be the best way/chart to visualize it?), so I'd like to keep the time intact for better maneuver later on, not like how I separated them into the year, month, day. I have tried setting time as an index and `resample()`, but that didn't work for me.

I would appreciate the help!

Comment: `pd.crosstab(df['time'].dt.normalize(), df['Hit/Miss'])`?

Comment: @Corralien I could cry.... that worked. I have not even tried that again since it didn't work last night. How can I now aggregate by hour or month and still have the full timestamp show? When I do pd.crosstab(df['time'].dt.hour, df['Hit/Miss']) the integer values shown for the time column don't make sense

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `offsets` to aggregate your data:

```
HM_DD = pd.crosstab(df['time'].dt.normalize(), df['Hit/Miss'])
HM_MM = pd.crosstab(df['time'].dt.date+pd.offsets.MonthBegin(-1), df['Hit/Miss'])
HM_YYMM = pd.crosstab(df['time'].dt.date+pd.offsets.YearBegin(-1), df['Hit/Miss'])
```

Output:

```
>>> HM_DD.reset_index().rename_axis(columns=None)
        time  FN  FP  TP
0 2016-09-29   2   0   1
1 2016-10-05   0   1   0

>>> HM_MM.reset_index().rename_axis(columns=None)
        time  FN  FP  TP
0 2016-09-01   2   0   1
1 2016-10-01   0   1   0

>>> HM_YYMM.reset_index().rename_axis(columns=None)
        time  FN  FP  TP
0 2016-01-01   2   1   1
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Could you please explain what offsets does and how that changed my result from showing integers to full dates? I tried to read it in the documents but still don't understand it fully.

Comment: `df['time'].dt.date` keep the date part (YYYY-MM-DD) but DD can be 1 to 31 so using `MonthBegin(-1)` reset the day to YYYY-MM-01. It's like group by year and month only.